# How to say texstudio to come out from nonstop mode?

Tags: errors, texstudio

While working on texstudio, I am finding the following difficulty.

Sometimes knowingly or unknowingly we are giving wrong commands which forces to go to the non-stop mode. At that time if we restart the machine, it works fine(provided after correcting the error).

But, my question is

> Is there any way to force my texstudio to come out from the non-stop mode and to work with the new codes(which I have corrected)?

In the latest version, I am having stop compile button which is right to the compile button. That does the job.

Comment: I don't know texstudio but most IDEs run tex in nonstopmode or similar so that they can collect all the errors in one run and allow you to step through them, if it stopped on first error it could show less information about errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by installing the new version of texstudio.

Now the latest version of Texstudio is coming with one  button to stop compile which changes to red in color while compiling..

Press that button if it is non stop mode, it will revert back to normal mode.

I have given two snapshots which gives you the position of the button and color before and while compiling.

[image]

[image]